# fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Hoy estaba probando el code::blocks como ide para dejar de usar dev-c++ puesto que me habían dicho que este era mejor, naturalmente mi primer programa ahí fue un "hola mundo" pero me encontré con este error que nunca había ocurrido con dev-c++

**||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Programación c++\Untitled1.c|3|fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|**

El código es así:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main(){

cout<<"hola"<<endl;

system("pause");
}
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: te recomiendo que leas esta pagina de un usuario qqu tiene el mismo error. al parecer CB no cuenta con compilador solo es edición de código http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=22006.0

Comment: Tu archivo se llama `Untitled1.c`. Este es un archivo C , no un archivo C++. C y C++ son lenguajes de programación diferentes. Cambias el nombre de tu archivo a `algo.cpp`.

Comment: Era eso, gracias por la ayuda :D

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    cout<<"hola mundo"<<endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

prueba el siguiente codigo y comenta que tal te fue!

Comment: Sale el mismo error :( creo que es algo externo al código

Answer (score 0):

yo tuve el mismo problema y lo solucioné  simplemente guardando el archivo con la extensión "cpp" es decir *myFirstProgram.cpp* aunque parezca obvio que la extensión será establecida por defecto, Code::Blocks no lo hace por ello no detecto el "iostream" besos